# Should one give up Moha?

Tags: vashishta, yoga-vashishtha

In the book Yoga Vashistha(page 426) , Vashistha says one should give up moha as the snake casts off the skin.

My question is : should one give up moha and what is the meaning of the word moha ?

Comment: Pure sanskrit language questions are off-topic for the site. I don't see anything about Hinduism in the question. A google search returned me Buddhism related articles and pages. [Three Poisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_poisons) is a Buddhist concept not Hinduism concept. It is better if you post it on [Buddhism.se].

Comment: I would also recommend asking in http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language . That proposal needs more questions like this.

Comment: The term moha is in Gita 18.7

Comment: Moha is the extreme form of kama. Kama, krodha, lobha when heightened become moha, mada and matsarya respectively. Yes, one should give up moha.

Comment: This is not a pure language Q nor a Q about Buddhism. Moha is one of the arishadvargas, a very Hindu concept. Plus the Q is seeking a commentary on a statement that appears in a Hindu text. Reopen.

Comment: @Sarva No Wrong! it's Hinduism related only.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Check the revision history and who reopened.

Comment: @moonstar It was a question about Buddhism. The OP changed to Hinduism question later.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I never mentioned Buddhsim. I had asked what is the meaning of raga ,dosa and moha?

Comment: @Sarva What should We do when the whole content has been changed ? That reopen thing is done after this edit only.

Comment: @DheerajVerma As I said earlier in the comment, Raga, Dosa, Moha are called Three Poisons which is a Buddhism concept. You were asking about Sanskrit meanings of those terms. We only accpet them when they are backed by Hinduism concepts.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I never mentioned Buddhism. Those are Sanskrit words.

Comment: We don't give meanings to Sanskrit words here.  It is off-topic for us. We give it if they are related to Hinduism. Please see this [google search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=raga+dosa+moha). All are Buddhism related articles. If you want to continue use [Hinduism Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism).

Comment: @Sarvabhouma That is why I made it contextual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, would be good to give up moha.
Patanjali uses the word in YS II.34. Patanjali is an extensively commented author. It is usually understood as blind attachment, delusion.  He names moha as one of the causes to "perverse, unwholesome, troublesome, or deviant thoughts", what is obviously an serious obstacle to your practice.

Comment: You must format answer with proper quotations. If you are just commenting, thrn use comment boxes not answer boxes. What is YS II.34 , kindly mention properly.

Answer (score 2):

Bhagavad Gita speaks about the dangers of delusion (moha).

> **Deluded** by the mental states accruing from the three Gunas of Prakrti,
>   this world knows not Me, the Imperishable, transcending these Gunas.

Gita 7.13

> Niyatasya tu samnyasah karmano nopapadyate
>   **mohat** tasya parityagas tamasah parikirtitah
>
> It is not at all proper to renounce works that ought to be done as 
>   duty. Their abandonment out of delusion is considered to be of the 
>   nature of Tamas.

Gita 18.7

The word mohat means out of delusion.
Finally what are these delusions brought in by our mind?

> **The mind brings before us all our delusions — body, sex, creed, caste,
>   bondage**; so we have to tell the truth to the mind incessantly, until
>   it is made to realise it. Our real nature is all bliss, and all the
>   pleasure we know is but a reflection, an atom, of that bliss we get
>   from touching our real nature. That is beyond both pleasure and pain.
>   It is the "witness" of the universe, the unchanging reader before whom
>   turn the leaves of the book of life.

The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 8, Lectures and Discourses, Discourses on Jnana-Yoga - II

Answer (score 0):

> यदा ते **मोह**कलिलं बुद्धिर्व्यतितरिष्यति ।
>   तदा गन्तासि निर्वेदं श्रोतव्यस्य श्रुतस्य च ॥
>   —Bhagavad Gītā 2.52
>
> *yadā `when` te `thy` **mōha**`delusion`kalilaṁ`thicket, heap, confusion` buddhir`intelligence, enlightenment, mental determination`vyatitariṣyati`it shall pass beyond, it shall cross over`,
>
>   tadā `then` gantāsi `thou shalt go` nirvedaṁ `indifferent; disgusted` śrotavyasya `of that which is to be heard` śrutasya `of the heard` ca `and`*
>   —transliteration
>
> When thy intelligence shall cross beyond the whirl of **delusion**,
>   then shalt thou become indifferent to Scripture heard or that which thou hast yet to hear.
>   —Sri Aurobindo
>
> When your understanding passes beyond the swamp of **delusion**,
>   you will be indifferent to all that is heard in Sacred Lore.
>   —B. Miller
>
> Once your *buddhi* has crossed beyond the snares of **temptation**,
>   you shall have become indifferent to the Scriptures you have yet to hear and those which you have heard.
>   —personal translation

The above verses do not instruct us to shed mōha, but speak of that shedding as an inevitable future. Confusion & ignorance should indeed be shed. However, do not *try* to remove delusions. They will fall away naturally through practice. If you aim to shed confusing, then you are acting with your focus on the fruit of the actions.

Just as a snake needs its skin for a time, certain delusions are useful for learning about a particular aspect of Self. Once a misconception is no longer useful, it falls away naturally, just as natural as a snake shedding skin.

There have been times I didn't realize I had shed a delusion until I saw another experiencing it, thinking, "Oh, I remember that."

> क्रोधाद्भवति स**म्मोहः** संमोहात्स्मृतिविभ्रमः ।
>   स्मृतिभ्रंशाद् बुद्धिनाशो बुद्धिनाशात्प्रणश्यति ॥
>   —Bhagavad Gītā 2.63
>
> *krodhād`from wrath`bhavati`it comes to be` sa**ṁmohaḥ**`delusion, confusion` sa**ṁmohā**t`from delusion, from confusion`smṛti`remembered wisdom, memory`vibhramaḥ`wandering away`,
>
>   smṛtibhraṁśād`from memory wandering away` buddhi`intelligence`nāśo`destruction, loss` buddhināśāt`from destruction of intelligence`praṇaśyati`one is lost, he is destroyed`*
>   —transliteration
>
> Anger leads to **bewilderment**, from **bewilderment** comes loss of memory;
>   and by that the intelligence is destroyed; from destruction of intelligence he perishes.
>   —Sri Aurobindo
>
> From anger comes **confusion**, from **confusion** memory lapses,
>   from broken memory understanding is lost, from loss of understanding he is ruined.
>   —B. Miller
>
> Anger leads to **confusion** and **the confused** forget wisdom,
>   forgotten wisdom leads to destruction of *buddhi* and those without buddhi are lost.
>   —personal translation

From this line we can tell that wisdom is our natural state, but confusion—mohā—leads to forgetting that wisdom. By reducing anger, confusion is reduced as a byproduct.

> इच्छाद्वेषसमुत्थेन द्वन्द्व**मोहे**न भारत ।
>   सर्वभूतानि स**म्मोहं** सर्गे यान्ति परन्तप ॥
>   —Bhagavad Gītā 7.27
>
> icchādveṣasamutthena dvandva**mohe**na bhārata,
>   sarvabhūtāni sa**ṁmohaṁ** sarge yānti paraṁtapa.
>   —transliteration
>
> By the **delusion** of the dualities which arises from wish and disliking,
>   O Bharata, all existences in the creation are led into **bewilderment**.
>   —Sri Aurobindo’s Interpretation
>
> All creatures are bewildered at birth by the **delusion**
>   of opposing dualities that arise from desire and hatred.
>   —B. Miller
>
> Because of the arising of desire and hatred—because of the **deluding** (power) of the opposites, Arjuna,
>   All beings fall into **delusion** at birth.
>   —W. Sergeant
>
> By the welling up of desire and aversion—by the **delusion** of *dvaṃdvá*—Child of Bharata,
>   at birth, all beings fall into **delusion**, oh Scorcher of Foes.
>   —personal translation

Because of the illusion of duality, all are born into *mōha*. So, we have forgotten self-wisdom before we incarnated here. Once released of *dvaṃdvá*, *mōha* is gone (BG. 15.5). But having it, we are in a hell of attachment (BG. 16.16).

> तद्विद्धि प्रणिपातेन परिप्रश्नेन सेवया ।
>   उपदेक्ष्यन्ति ते ज्ञानं ज्ञानिनस्तत्त्वदर्शिनः ॥
>   यज्ज्ञात्वा न पुन**र्मोह**मेवं यास्यसि पाण्डव ।
>   येन भूतान्यशेषाणि द्रक्ष्यस्यात्मन्यथो मयि ॥
>   —Bhagavad Gītā 4.34-35
>
> tadviddhi praṇipātena paripraśnena sevayā,
>   upadekṣyanti te jñānaṁ jñāninastattvadarśinaḥ
>   yajjñātvā na punar**moha**mevaṁ yāsyasi pāṇḍava,
>   yena bhūtānyaśeṣāṇi drakṣyasyātmanyatho mayi.
>   —Transliteration
>
> Learn that by worshipping the feet of the teacher, by questioning and by service; the men of knowledge who have seen (not those who know merely by the intellect) the true principles of things, will instruct thee in knowledge.
>   Possessing that knowledge thou shalt not fall again into **the mind’s ignorance**, O Pandava; for by this, thou shalt see all existences without exception in the Self, then in Me.
>   —Sri Aurobindo’s Interpretation
>
> Know it by humble submission, by asking questions, and by service;
>   wise men who see reality will give you knowledge.
>   Arjuna, when you have realized this, you will not descend into **delusion** again;
>   knowledge will let you see creatures within yourself and so in me.
>   — B. Miller
>
> Know this! By humble prostration, by enquiry, by service;
>   Those who know themselves—who perceive *tattva*—will point it out;
>   Thus having self-knowledge, never again shall you fall into **delusion**, Child of Pāṇḍu;
>   with it you shall behold all beings in your *ātmán* and then in me.
>   —personal translation

There can be no *mōha* for those who see all others in the self and the self in all others. The Bhagavad Gītā mentions several times that *mōha* is born of *tamas* (BG. 14.8, 14.13, 14.17, 18.7, 18.39, )

Comment: Moha is a Hindu concept also. Moha means ignorance about reality, illusion, ignorance, mental obsession, infatuation, fascination, deep attachment etc.

Comment: I didn't know that. If so, I'm not sure how to differentiate it from *avidya* or *maya*. I'll research my answer and improve it.

Comment: One should not give in to delusion or moha and act in a wrong manner. Not giving into delusion is true for all spiritual aspirants regardless of which Vedanta school they are following. It has nothing to do with avidya of Advaita Vedanta.

Comment: What I mean is, from my Western perspective, ignorance, delusion, and forgetting-the-true-nature-of-self are the same regardless of philosophical school. There is some subtlety in the language I will have to research to better understand. That is, for my personal understanding, I need more linguistic knowledge before I can even discuss the philosophy of the matter.

Comment: Kindly give scriptural basis and references to what you write in answers.

Comment: Three hours later.... How's that?